# Call to method that recieves list of derived class doesn't compile in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm trying to uderstand why I can't pass list of derived class type to a function that defined to get list of the base class type as parameter.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using std::list;
class foo {

};

class bar : foo {

};
static void print_all(list<foo*> &L) {

}
void main() {
    list<foo*> LF;
    list<bar*> LB;
    print_all(LB); // error
    print_all(LF); // works fine
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because `list<foo*>` and `list<bar*>` are not related. They are independent types.

Comment: While a `bar*` can be passed to a function expecting `foo*` (due to the inheritance) once you make it any more complicated than that the types will no longer be compatible.

Comment: Not your print_all function has to handle polymorphism, but your list. `list<foo*> LB; LB.push_back(new bar());`

Comment: This is a [type variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)) issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of being templates, `std::list<foo*>` and `std::list<bar*>` are entirely unrelated types. But even if this was not about templates (you might try to explicitly install such a relation via inheritance), there's a good reason for why this still would not work out well (assuming it *would* be legal...):

```
void f(std::list<foo*>& l)
{
    l.push_back(new foo());
}

void g()
{
    std::list<bar*> l;
    f(l);
    // now l contains a foo object that is not a bar one!!!
}
```

By the way: have you ever noticed that C++ STL does not ever pass containers to functions? You might try the same approach:

```
template <typename Iterator>
void print_all(Iterator begin, Iterator end)
{
    for(; begin != end; std::advance(begin))
    {
        // print *begin
    }
}

print_all(lf.begin(), lf.end());
print_all(lb.begin(), lb.end());
```

Comment: `list<foo *>` and `list<bar *>` are unrelated types, but it is not because `list` is a template.     An array of `foo *` and an array of `bar *` are also unrelated types.

Comment: @Peter Hm, I'd say it still is true - but it's not the only reason for which types can be unrelated... My point was rather contrasting against inheritance: `MyFooList { }; MyBarList : public MyFooList { }` while one possibly *could* implement classes alike, one would quickly fall into all the trouble shown in this answer...

Comment: another solution is to use templates:
[code](https://gist.github.com/SuperC4ctus/6cd7f5dff3d2fe9a27c7baef901d6f9a)

Comment: @Cactus Actually, I'm using templates as well... My variant resembles more the pattern people know very well from the STL, so in this case, I'd prefer it. Still your variant is nice, too, and would be perfect for data types not supporting iterators... Too bad the question is closed already, would have liked you to have posted it as your own answer.

Comment: @Aconcagua sorry I read too fast, yours is definitly better when the type is iterable.

Answer (score 1):

If your aim is just to print the information from `foo` and `bar`, you don't need two lists, you can have a single list which has as its parameter the base class pointer (`foo`'s pointer) and a `print` function which is `virtual`.

Then your code will be:

```
class foo {
    public:
    virtual void print() { cout<< "printing foo\n"; }
};

class bar :  public foo {
    public:
    void print() { cout<< "printing bar\n"; }
};
static void print_all(list<foo*>& L) {
    for(auto const& i: L)
    {
        i->print();
    }
}
int main() {

    list<foo*> LB;
    foo f;
    bar b;
    LB.push_back(&f);
    LB.push_back(&b);
    print_all(LB);     
}
```

See [demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a54ae58540d3c540).